# Sorting each columns and displaying only the largest value from CSV - powershell

Tags: powershell

I am try to sort the list of columns in CSV. It doesn't sort in a right format, as the object type is system.array.

I am able to get the value for a single column individually by doing a type casting. Is there a way to do a type casting for all the columns. The below code works only for a single column.

timestamp|`abc | A     |  B  |  C   |   D  |  E   |  F  |  G    |

6/4/2019` |`6775 |  3059 |  4  | 2292 | 1328 | 764  |  0 |  0  |

6/4/2019` |`6910 |  3167 |  28 | 3568 | 1180 | 1348 |  0 |  0  |

6/4/2019` |`6749 |  3161 |  0  | 2180 | 2060 | 1440 |  0 |  28 |

6/5/2019` |`6738 |  3118 |  4  | 2736 | 1396 | 984  |  0 |  0  |

6/5/2019` |`6718 |  3130 |  12 | 3076 | 1008 | 452  |  0 |  4  |

6/5/2019` |`6894 |  3046 |  4  | 2284 | 1556 | 624  |  0 |  0  |`

This the sample csv data.

```
$csv=Import-Csv 'M:\MyDoc\script\logfiles\streams_OUTPUT.csv'
$uniquedates=$csv |select timestamp -Unique 
$resultTab  = @();
foreach ($d in $uniquedates)
$array_name = $csv |where {$_.timestamp -like $d.timestamp } | Sort- Object @{expression={if($_.A){[int[]]$_.A}}} -Descending | Select -First 1
$resultTab += $array_name;
}
$resultTab | FT
```

My desired output, what I am looking for is :

`timestamp  streams A     B   C    D     E     F  G

6/4/2019   6910    3167  28  3568 2060  1440  0  28
6/5/2019   6894    3130  12  3076 1556  984   0  4`

Comment: what are you seeking? it LOOKS like you want the highest item from each column that has the same date stamp. the sample output you show is NOT a sort - the row shown does not match any of the input rows.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Hi Lee, yes you are correct, I am trying to find the highest item from each column. What I am trying to do is sort the column and display the highest value. It only works for one column. I am not sure how to type cast all the columns and convert it into Integer. I am also not sure if there is any other way too

Comment: do you want to find the `highest` time stamp also?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey for timestamp I am already selecting the unique values. So In the csv I have an entire month data, where each day(timestamp) have number of values, so I sort the values first for each timestamp and then take the highest values. But this works only for one column.

Comment: thanks! [*grin*] that makes things a good deal easier. take a look at my answer to this ...

Comment: you show `streams` in your output ... but you show `abc` in your input. which is correct? [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[edit - changed the sample data to the new version & changed the code to work with the new specifications.]*

here's one way to do the job. [*grin*] it uses the way that PoSh allows getting all the values of a single property from a collection at one swoop. `$Collection.PropName` will give you all the values ready to work on.

```
# fake reading in a CSV
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$InStuff = @'
timestamp, abc, A, B, C, D, E, F, G
6/4/2019, 6775, 3059, 4, 2292, 1328, 764, 0, 0
6/4/2019, 6910, 3167, 28, 3568, 1180, 1348, 0, 0
6/4/2019, 6749, 3161, 0, 2180, 2060, 1440, 0, 28
6/5/2019, 6738, 3118, 4, 2736, 1396, 984, 0, 0
6/5/2019, 6718, 3130, 12, 3076, 1008, 452, 0, 4
6/5/2019, 6894, 3046, 4, 2284, 1556, 624, 0, 0
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$TargetPropertyList = $InStuff[0].PSObject.Properties.Name.Where({$_ -ne 'TimeStamp'})

$GroupedInStuff = $InStuff |
    Group-Object -Property TimeStamp

$Results = foreach ($GIS_Item in $GroupedInStuff)
    {
    $HighestValues = [ordered]@{
        TimeStamp = $GIS_Item.Name
        }
    foreach ($TPL_Item in $TargetPropertyList)
        {
        $TempHiVal = ($GIS_Item.Group.$TPL_Item.ForEach({[int]$_}) | Sort-Object)[-1]
        $HighestValues.Add($TPL_Item, $TempHiVal)
        }

    [PSCustomObject]$HighestValues
    }

$Results = $Results |
    Sort-Object -Property {[datetime]$_.TimeStamp}

$Results |
    Format-Table
```

output ...

```
TimeStamp  abc    A  B    C    D    E F  G
---------  ---    -  -    -    -    - -  -
6/4/2019  6910 3167 28 3568 2060 1440 0 28
6/5/2019  6894 3130 12 3076 1556  984 0  4
```

please, remember to NOT use `Format-Table` [or the other `Format-*` cmdlets] for anything other than *final display* or *output to a plain text file*. they chop up your objects, wrap them in *formatting code*, and then spit them out. it will produce garbage if you try to use the output for any added work.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But what I am trying is to display the highest value for each timestamp. I am not sure what is missing from my end. I tried using unique and selected the timestamp but it didn't worked.

Comment: I have so many timestamps (like 6/4/2019, 6/5/2019/, it goes on) and each timestamp have many values as 6/4/2019. Not sure who to loop this up for each transaction get the highest value of each timestamp.

Comment: i thot you said that you had already grouped things by timestamp. [*frown*] your sample data has _only one value for the timestamp_ ... so i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @BijoDev - please, add a sample data set that show what you will _actually be working with_. now you are saying there are several time stamps ... so include a few. [*grin*]

Comment: I have added the desired output now and change the sample data. I was able to get the highest value only for one column. Using the unique feature for timestamp and calling it in the loop it works but only for one column

Comment: @BijoDev - i have modified the answer to reflect your changed sample data and modified specifications. it should work now. ///// in the future PLEASE try to make accurate specifications about what you will be working with. this entire back-n-forth was totally unneeded. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: thank you so much, it work perfect. I will make sure to fill in full details next time

Comment: @BijoDev - you are quite welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Comment: a small doubt here. I was also trying to get the average from these columns. I tried to use the same script and added this : 
$TempHiVal = ($GIS_Item.Group.$TPL_Item.ForEach({[int]$_}) | Measure-Object -Average * )
Am I doing something wrong. or missing something

Comment: @BijoDev - what are you wanting to average? all the values in a row or all the values in each source column?

Comment: @BijoDev - i an reluctant to modify the answer after so much time. if you need this as a full script, open a new question. ///// however, replacing the `$TempHiVal =` code with this >>> `[math]::Round(($GIS_Item.Group.$TPL_Item.ForEach({[int]$_}) | Measure-Object -Average).Average, 2)` <<< seems to work.

Comment: thank you so much for responding. Yes I am trying to get the average for each source column. I tried this code which you have mentioned but I get an error stating "Index was outside the bounds of the array". But I will try to re-modify something or the other.

Comment: post a new question so that i can post complete code. i deleted the one i made, but can redo that pretty quickly. the one i made had both `Propname_Hi` and `PropName_Av` for each column - if you want that much info. [*grin*]

Comment: Sure then I will post another question. I will try for sometime, if there is no luck. Then I will post it for sure. Thank you so much.